# how to restore and store two String values?

Tags: android

I have two values how can i store and restore it.

```
public void SetCaseInfo(String PatientType, String Teethsselected) { // All objects are from android.context.Context
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(DEALSPOTR_PREFS, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString(PatientType, Teethsselected);
    editor.commit();
}

public String getCaseInfo() {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(DEALSPOTR_PREFS, 0);
    String value = settings.getString(PatientType, Teethsselected);
    return value;
}
```

is it correct?

Comment: Are you facing any problems here..?

Comment: @ntc if `PatientType` is a string that has multiple values he will be always saving `Teethsselected` with the key `PatientType`. this means he can't retrieve `Teethsselected` except if he knows the value of `PatientType`. If he wants to save the two strings, each string must have a key for itself.

Comment: @Sheriff.. you just can't judge it by seeing his question. when i see his post it seems like he has made "PatientType, Teethsselected", as class variables. There should't be any problem if he is not initializing them multiple times.

Comment: @ntc It seems more rational and fair to judge based on his question `I have two values how can i store and restore it.`

Comment: @Sheriff.. You are right.:).. i never bothered to see what is he asking. just had look at the code...

Answer (score 3):

In your code, `PatientType` must not change so you can be able to retrieve Teethsselected

You are not saving the ***2 strings***

```
public void SetCaseInfo(String PatientType, String Teethsselected) { // All objects are from android.context.Context
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(DEALSPOTR_PREFS, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("teeth", Teethsselected);
    editor.putString("patient", PatientType);
    editor.commit();
}

public String getTeethsselected() {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(DEALSPOTR_PREFS, 0);
    String value = settings.getString("teeth", "default");
    return value;
}

public String getPatientType() {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(DEALSPOTR_PREFS, 0);
    String value = settings.getString("patient", "default");
    return value;
}
```

Comment: public void SetCaseInfo(String PatientType,String Teethsselected){
   // All objects are from android.context.Context
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(DEALSPOTR_PREFS, 0);
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
       editor.putString(TYPE,PatientType);    
       editor.putString(TEETHS,Teethsselected);  
       mPatientType=PatientType;
       mTeethselected=Teethsselected;
       // Commit the edits!
       editor.commit();
 }

Comment: public void restorePreferredCaseInfo(String type,String Teeths) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       // Restore preferences
       SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(DEALSPOTR_PREFS, 0);
       mPatientType = settings.getString(TYPE,type);
       mTeethselected=settings.getString(TEETHS,Teeths);
 }

Comment: @user828948 why didnt you use the functions in my answer? you will have to use 1 function to retrieve each value so you will need 2 functions for the two values.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing only one value here:

```
editor.putString(PatientType, Teethsselected);
```

here PatientType is the key, not the value you want to save.
Likewise, you are restoring only one value here:

```
String value = settings.getString(PatientType, Teethsselected);
```

`Teethsselected` is the default value for the key `PatientType`. If it's what you intended, than yes, it is correct.